# Xamarin Forms draw waveforms while recording audio

Tags: c#, audio, xamarin.forms, visualizer

While recording audio with Xamarin Forms, draw a waveform, like [MusicBar](https://github.com/emadabdalrahman/MusicBar)

Recording and playback can be done with [Plugin.AudioRecorder](https://github.com/NateRickard/Plugin.AudioRecorder). I don't know how to draw the waveform.

Thanks for helping!

Comment: You have not asked a question.

Comment: One solution is to use GIF Image of the wave.

Comment: @Paul,if you want to draw waveforms when recording audo, you can consider to use NAudio. https://www.assembleforce.com/2012-07/how-to-draw-waveform-while-recording-using-naudio-and-wpf.h

Comment: @CherryBu This is exactly what I want, thank you very much!

Comment: Unfortunately, The audio devices in NAudio support Windows only

Comment: @PaulZhang have you get any solution to draw the waveform. I also need same thing. Please let me know if you have any solution to draw waveform.